# How to use sed to replace variable value declared in a text file

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to edit the `/etc/environment` file to change the `MY_VARIABLE` from `VALUE_01` to `VALUE_02`.

Here is the context of the `/etc/environment` file:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk8/jdk1.8.0_92-1"
MY_VARIABLE=VALUE_01
```

Ideally I would like to use `sed` command to edit it, for example (please note it is not working command):

`sed -e 'MY_VARIABLE=VALUE_02' -i /etc/environment`

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -- 's/MY_VARIABLE=.*/MY_VARIABLE=VALUE_02/' /etc/environment
```

Once you check it works, add the `-i` option:

```
sed -i -- 's/MY_VARIABLE=.*/MY_VARIABLE=VALUE_02/' /etc/environment
```

You will probably need root access.

Comment: I have to use `sed -i -e` flags to make it work. Please correct your answer so we could up vote it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Wait, are you sure you need the `-e` flag? What `sed` implementation do you have?

Comment: With `-i` flag I am getting `sed: 1: "/etc/environment": command c expects \ followed by text`. How can I check what `sed` implementation I have?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it... Probably nothing to do with your sed. It is caused by an improbable coincidence. But before I explain it, try `sed -i -- 's/MY_VARIABLE=.*/MY_VARIABLE=VALUE_02/' /etc/environment`.

Comment: `--` is a POSIX construct to indicate end of options. If you don't use it and have a particular filename, beginning with a `-`, it may be treated as an option by your utility. For example, consider `touch '-a'` vs `touch -- '-a'`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use `sed -i` and hoping your version of `sed` implements that option and working out if it takes a mandatory argument or not (I have a feeling you're not using GNU `sed` like the `linux` tag suggests you should be), just use `ed` to edit files in scripts.

```
ed -s /etc/environment <<EOF
/^MY_VARIABLE=/c
MY_VARIABLE=VALUE_02
.
w
EOF
```

**c**hanges the first line starting with `MY_VARIABLE=` to the given new text, and **w**rites the file back to disk.